# how to write query for createing dataset in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-analytics

we have two different document in single bucket and i want to create dataset of these different document .....
and i write query for that like this..
please help me to write query

***`CREATE DATASET case2user ON  (select r.*, a.* from case2 r INNER JOIN case2 a ON r.user.userID = a.user.userID)`***
[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3vn8.png)

but i am not able to create dataset
how to write query for  createing  dataset in couchbase db

Comment: I don't think you can create a dataset as a result of a `SELECT` query. Take a look at the tutorial here: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/analytics/primer-beer.html and the DDL docs here: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/analytics/5_ddl.html - once you've created a dataset, you can execute the `SELECT` on the dataset.

Comment: @MatthewGroves thanks for replying... i have seen tutorial but i didn't found any things... Any other way to create dataset using join